# Python interpret bytearray as bytes

Tags: python-3.x, byte

I have a question regarding the interpretation of a string as bytes

Within python, I have the situation that one variable contains e.g. this value

```
"bytearray(b'\x13\x02US')"
```

this is unfortunately due to the behavior of a module I am using. My question is, how could i get this string into bytes?

I have tried stripping away the "bytearray(b'" and the "')" at the end, and use .encode() as a function, but the result then is:

```
b'\\x13\\x02US'
```

Which clearly escapes the \ in order to prevent the interpretation as bytes.

How could i get this converted into

```
b'\x13\x02US'
```

instead though?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use .decode().replace('\\', '\'), this way it replaces the double slashes with single ones. Either attache it after your .encode() function or do it on your string seperately.